# Firefox ignoring "top" in table cell element

Tags: css, firefox

For some reason firefox (and firefox alone, this isn't even an issue on ie which is...odd) seems to be ignoring the `top:xx%` value of a table/table cell element, but only initially, if the value is edited in the console however it immediately works as intended.

```
.overlay nav {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 50%; /* <---the issue */
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I've settled the issue for the now by switching to `top:xxvh`, however I'm curious as to why the precentage isn't working so I'm still asking the question to see if anyone can shed some light on the issue.

[Codepen showing example, only occurs in firefox](https://codepen.io/xeyreon/pen/RRmLEb)

Comment: why use table-cell? does the parent have a defined width?

Comment: I ended up using it because it seemed to handle responsive placement better (particularly on mobile browsers) than simply using height and top alone, and yes the parent has a defined width (100%).

Comment: Why would you need to position a table-cell in the first place? You already have `vertical-align:middle`? --- And it doesn't even make sense to use `transform:translateY(-50%)` together with `height:100%` and `top:50%`. I mean you position the element from the top just to transform it back the same amount!? Transform-translate with percentage takes the items dimensions for calculation while positioning takes the parents dimensions. But you set both respective dimensions exactly the same with `height:100%`.

Comment: Percentage values always need fixed dimensions at some point in their hierarchical calculation. --- Additionally see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position (*"The effect of 'position:relative' on [... table ...] elements is undefined."*). So you have been in sheer luck that some browsers somehow do what you intended. --- I recommend to just getting rid of the table-elements or at least use wrappers inside table cells around your positioning elements.

Comment: To be honest those were in before I had switched to the `table`/`table-cell` structure and hadn't caused an issue until I viewed the example in firefox. Removing the `top` and `transform` seem to alleviate the issue as well, so I'll do that instead of using vh (it's definitely cleaner), I just found it odd that it hadn't caused any issues in chrome-desktop and mobile, safari-desktop and mobile, ie, and opera, yet firefox somehow broke it lol.